# -> operator in if (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

I am new to C++, recently I saw a code as a follows

```
 if (A1 -> B1) A1->B1->C1(numbers);
```

I have difficulty to understand this simple line.
Could you please advise me?
I guess, it says, if pointer A1 is assigned to B1(true) then point A1 to B1 and B to function C1, am I right?
Thanks for your help

Comment: This is equivalent of writing `if (A1 -> B1 != nullptr)`

Comment: This means if `A1->B1` is not null, call `C1` which is a member of `A1->B1`.

Comment: Things are much more readable *without* `" -> "` (spaces) surrounding the `'->'` operator...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a class or struct somewhere in your code. unlike`.` operator `->` is used to access a member of a struct or a class which is pointed by a pointer.
let's assume our classes looks something like this;

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void C1(int numbers);
};

class Bar
{
public:
  Foo* B1;    //pointer to B1 object.
};
```

let's also assume somewhere in the code we had a pointer declared and we try to access the member of object that is pointed by the pointer.

```
Foo* myFoo; //pointer myFoo is declared. 
myFoo->C1; //trying to access C1 function what  myFoo is pointing at.
```

in the above example, we are trying to access the member of myFoo with `->`. The problem is though myFoo doesn't point to anything.. we only declared the pointer but not assigned to an address of any particilar`Foo` object. Therefore, using `->` operator to access the pointer members would cause undefined behaviour. So in order to combat this possible problem that may occur in the code, we can guard the myFoo with a nullptr check before accessing it's member

```
Foo* myFoo = nullptr;
```

we can now check if myFoo is valid or not with.

```
if(myFoo)
   myFoo->C1(1); //if its valid call the C1 function.
```

above code accesses the member of myFoo only if myFoo is valid.

going back to your example we can now assume what's going on.

```
       if(A1->B1) //check if the B1 pointer of the A1 is valid.
          A1->B1->C1(3); //if it is valid, call the C1 function of the object B1 pointing to.
```